# how can i stack the open documents (textedit) file icons in the dock?

Tags: macos, dock

I have about 20 textedit documents open and don't like seeing them in the dock.  Is there a way to stack them so that they take up only one space on the dock?  Or not show them at all?

Comment: That's too bad I got a downvote, given that your closure message says "While what’s on- and off-topic is not always intuitive" and I've never violated the rules before. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In System Preferences > Dock, check "Minimize windows into application icon". Note that this doesn't affect any existing minimized windows, but it will affect windows you minimize from that point forward.

You can use any of several mechanisms to restore the windows:

- the Dock menu
- the application's Window menu
- application Exposé / “Application windows” in Mission Control, which you can also trigger from the Command-Tab application switcher with the up/down arrow keys

or any of several third-party apps/tools that help you with window management (e.g. Witch).

To not show them at all, just hide TextEdit entirely; you can do this with Command-H or by Option-clicking on another application's window (this includes the Desktop, which is technically a Finder window).

You might also consider using a text editor that supports placing documents in tabs, or something equivalent; while I'm a big fan of traditional Mac style window management, once you get up to 20 windows in an app, you're really in trouble :-)

Comment: Thank you So much for the thorough answer!!!!!  BTW which tab-based text editor do you like?

Comment: If you're the kind of person who doesn't mind getting his/her hands dirty with text file configuration, then Sublime Text is terrific. Otherwise I'd recommend TextWrangler/BBEdit.  If you primarily do Web development, also check out Espresso and Coda.

Comment: I use textWrangler and usually have a bunch of xml files open at once.  Will check out these.  Thanks a bunch Nicholas!